# Copy/Clone files from File Input to another Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

If i open a file select, select a file, then click file select again and then click cancel, it forgets the originally selected file

```
//Main input
<input type="file" class="input" id="input" name="avatar">

//Backup input
<input type="file" class="input_two" id="input_two" name="avatar_two">
```

Is there a workaround for this, possibly creating a temporary input class and copying the .files over to this one so that i can still have access to the last file

```
$('.input').change(function () {
        var value = this.files;
        console.log(value);
        if(value.length > 0)
        {
            $(.avatar_two).assign(value)... //This is what i want to do
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("nada");
        }
```

is this possible?

Comment: You can not set the value of an file input

Comment: function copy()
    {
      var myObject, f;
      myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      f = myObject.file.copy("c:\\test.txt", "c:\\mytest.txt");
    }

Comment: ActiveX? is it the 90s?

Comment: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined"* nice job at multi-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>It is not possible to set `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element, which references read-only `FileList` object.</strike> See [React/Javascript--FileReader/<input/>/adding image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677804/react-javascript-filereader-input-adding-image/).

You can call `File.prototype.slice()` to create a copy of the `File` object. Or use `FormData`, `FormData.prototype.append()` to store selected files.

```
var clone, i = 0;
var fd = new FormData();

$('.input').change(function() {
    var value = this.files;
    console.log(value);
    if (value.length > 0) {
        clone = value[0].slice(0, value[0].size, value[0].type);
        fd.append("file-" + (i++) /* this.name */, value[0]);
    } else {
        console.log("nada");
    }
});
```

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek alright, that's working, I get the clone and the fd values with the image I selected. But, how do you copy that into the backup input¿?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a)

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek thank you for replying, but at the end it seemed a bit complicated situation that I have. The 2 file input I have, have JS events bound to them, and I don't seem to be able to cope with that. Thank you anyway! I opted for a different way of solving it :)

Answer (score 7):

it is possible at 2021 via DataTransfer (at least latest chrome/firefox)

```js
let file = document.getElementById("file");
let back = document.getElementById("back");

file.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let files = this.files;
  let dt = new DataTransfer();
  for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    let f = files[i];
    dt.items.add(
      new File(
        [f.slice(0, f.size, f.type)],
        f.name
    ));
  }
  back.files = dt.files;
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" multiple>
<input type="file" id="back" multiple>
```

Comment: Great that works exactly as I need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you cannot do that for security reasons, at least setting the value, I don’t know if coping or cloning it’s possible but take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)