# JQuery: how can I push a file to another input array value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I have 2 inputs:

each time, I select some files form `temp` and I want push to another input `files`.

I do this step:

chage first iput:

```
<input type="file" id="temp" name="temp[]" onchange="readFile(this);" multiple />

function readFile(input) {
    counter = input.files.length;
     for(x = 0; x<counter; x++){
        if (input.files && input.files[x]) {
           const  reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function (e) {
              // add thumbnail picture
           }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);

        }
     }
}
```

I add this code to main js fuction:

```
            var  new_file = [];
            new_file["id"] = "1";
            new_file["main"] = "0";
            new_file["delete"] = "0";
            new_file["file"] = input.files[x];
            files = $("input[name='files[]']").val();
            if(!Array.isArray(files)) files = [];
            files.push(new_file);
            $("input[name='files[]']").val(input[x]);
```

So finall code:

```
function readFile(input) {
    counter = input.files.length;
     for(x = 0; x<counter; x++){
        if (input.files && input.files[x]) {
           const  reader = new FileReader();

            var  new_file = [];
            new_file["id"] = "1";
            new_file["main"] = "0";
            new_file["delete"] = "0";
            new_file["file"] = input.files[x];
            files = $("input[name='files[]']").val();
            if(!Array.isArray(files)) files = [];
            files.push(new_file);
            $("input[name='files[]']").val(input[x]);

           reader.onload = function (e) {
              // add thumbnail picture
           }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);

        }
     }
}
```

So I have 2 problem:

in server side, I got this:

```
 "files" => array:1 [▼
    0 => null
  ]
```

but temp is ok:

```
"temp" => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#1349 ▶}
 ]
```

Also, in line `new_file["file"] = input.files[x];`, input.files[x] is not a file. it is an object. how can insert file to new_file["file"]?

Comment: The value of a file input is not file object. This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) . What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You can't programmatically add files to an input for security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't move the value of one file input to another, it is a security risk.

From [copying the value of a form's file input field to another form's input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898077/copying-the-value-of-a-forms-file-input-field-to-another-forms-input-field)

---

If the end result you want to achieve is to have identical values for both the file inputs when user select files for `input[name="temp[]"]`, consider using clone and replace instead:

```
$('input[name="temp[]"]').change(function() {
  var $clone = $this.clone()
  $clone.attr('name', 'files[]');
  $('input[name="files[]"]').replaceWith($clone);
});
```